# React - How to secure content meant for admin user only?

Tags: javascript, django, reactjs, authentication, conditional-rendering

I'm in a process of converting Django based templates into a client side React app.
In Django I could control the rendering of a column like so:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Column 1</th>
    <th>Column 2</th>
    {% if user.is_staff %}
    <th>Column only for admins</th>
    {% endif %}
  </tr>
</table>
```

In React, I can use javascript if / ternary operator, but the content will still be visible in the output bundle.

What are the options in the case of client side apps?
 The only way I see is to create a completely different component for admin users, and then to render the component conditionally using some server logic (so it won't be served as a static file). This will be a serious headache though.

Comment: As for the the client side, you can make API calls to the options, and thus block the API calls that are not meant for specific users.

Comment: You need do to this sever side. You can hide it from the user on the front end, but all the data you're trying to hide will be still sent. Any user could just open dev tools and view it for example